# Unable to create URLSessionWebSocketTask with background configuration

Tags: ios, swift, foundation, urlsessionwebsockettask

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT.
>   The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.

I'm trying to create `URLSessionWebSocketTask` with backdround configuration in Playground, but unfortunately i'm getting above mentioned error

```
import Foundation

let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: .background(withIdentifier: "___ID___"))
let webSocketTask = urlSession.webSocketTask(with: URL(string: "wss://echo.websocket.org")!)
```

Answer (score 1):

I get it,

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background

**Comply with Background Transfer Limitations**

With background sessions, the actual transfer is performed by a process that is separate from your app’s process. Because restarting your app’s process is fairly expensive, a few features are unavailable, resulting in the following limitations:

- The session must provide a delegate for event delivery. (For uploads and downloads, the delegates behave the same as for in-process transfers.)
- Only HTTP and HTTPS protocols are supported (no custom protocols).
- Redirects are always followed. As a result, even if you have
  implemented
  urlSession(_:task:willPerformHTTPRedirection:newRequest:completionHandler:),
  it is not called.
- Only upload tasks from a file are supported (uploads from data
  instances or a stream fail after the app exits).